# I want to upload only updated files to google drive but XCOPY seems not working

Tags: batch-file, google-drive-api, backup, xcopy

I recently started using Google Drive as a corporate account to backup 10,000+ files.
Once I uploaded everything to G:\My Drive\  with taking 3 days.
Now for the operation, I would like to copy only updated files so I created batch file like following.

```
set TODAY=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%
set time2=%time: =0% 
set TIME=%time2:~0,2%%time2:~3,2%%time2:~6,2%
set LOGFILEPATH=C:\TEMP\%TODAY%_%TIME%.txt 
xcopy Z:\ORIGINAL G:\My Drive\BACKUP /D /S /R /Y /I /K /C /F /H 
>>%LOGFILEPATH%
```

It works for other folders like D drive (internal Hard disk drive) however, if you pointed to G drive (Google virtual drive??) then it does not work. i.e. the batch file does not produce any output.
Do you know any command or tools helping this situation?

Again, I want to copy only updated files to Google drive from internal hard disk drive with all the sub directory etc keeping same shape.

Thank you team,
Kaz

Comment: Do you have a directory in G:\ named `My`?

Comment: yes I have two preset directories called "My Drive" and "Team Drive" both on G drive when I installed Google drive module.

Comment: Compo means this "G:\My Drive\BACKUP" ;)

Comment: er! yes yes off course created it beforehand. It does exist and even if I added new file in the Z:\Original folder, it won't work.  I found a software doing this business without hassle using xcopy so it resolved but I don't know why xcopy does not work on G drive. (D drive or C drive it works perfectly).

Comment: @Tika9o9, my previous comment contains no mistakes or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following software resolve the issue.
I am not sure why XCOPY didn't work but the following software works perfectly even on Google drive.

[link]http://synchronicity.sourceforge.net/

if some of you achieved another way please let me know.

Comment: XCOPY did not work because you have SPACES in your path and any path with spaces or special characters need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Google drive is referenced with spaces here and secondly, include /M for incremental backup at the source destination side, below is the command skeleton:

XCopy /M [source loc]\*.* G:\"My Drive"\ShareDir /Y

Where, G: is Google Drive, /M will only picks up files that are new or changed & /Y will suppress prompt

Alternatively, use can use below command as well for incremental backup of entire directory:

ROBOCOPY [source location]\ShareDir G:\\"My Drive"\\ShareDir /MIR

Where, /MIR option will mirror the directory as it is (it takes care of the deleted or renamed files/directories as well). Note the use of double slashes.

It works for me; I keep my songs updated to my Google Drive, which I access through a Cloud Music Player.